# C++ Sfml Text output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I have recently started using SFML in C++ and I have a problem when it comes to drawing text. I managed to run the default program which draws a green circle to the window so I'm assuming there's no hardware problem. I'm using SFML 2.1 and Visual studio 2013.

Here's my code:

```
#ifdef SFML_STATIC
#pragma comment(lib, "glew.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "freetype.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "jpeg.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")  
#endif // SFML_STATIC

#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{

sf::RenderWindow mywindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

sf::Text text;

text.setString(std::string("Hello World!"));

text.setCharacterSize(24);

text.setColor(sf::Color::Red);

text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);

    mywindow.clear();

    mywindow.draw(text);

    mywindow.display();

    std::cin.get(); //To prevent the window automatically closing.

}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you draw the text you need to provide the font by making an sf::Font object, using its loadFromFile() function and then passing it as an argument to the sf::Text's setFont() function.

```
sf::Font font;
font.loadFromFile("file_path");
text.setFont(font);
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise it required a font to be provided, I remember reading somewhere about a default font and skipped steps. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of help! You probably read that from an older tutorial, if I recall correctly it was a recent change.

Answer (score 0):

Like those before me said, you need to set a font.

In fact the things you have to always think about when showing text are:

```cpp
sf::Text someText;
sf::Font someFont;

someFont.loadFromFile("txt_____.ttf");

someText.setFont(someFont);
someText.setCharacterSize(30);
someText.setString("text");
```

Also consider using the copy pasta from the official SFML website:

https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-draw.php

This copy pasta is an infinite loop so as long as its open your program will draw what it needs to draw one frame by a time. I added a similar example to yours to it. Fonts are placed in the **BUILD** folder of your project. They can be found online or in "C:/windows/fonts". Just copy paste into your build folder.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Text someText;
    sf::Font someFont;

    someFont.loadFromFile("txt_____.ttf");

    someText.setFont(someFont);
    someText.setCharacterSize(30);
    someText.setString("text");

    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);
        window.draw(someText);
        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```